# Connect to other computers for copying files using Tcl/Tk

Tags: tcl

I am trying to Tcl script to connect remote computers to copy multiple files to my PC.

I tried to use ftp package as below but it always fails and gets constant -1 even if correct ip/user/pwd.

Can you help me out? Thanks a lot.

```
package require ftp
set ip aaa
set user bbb
set pwd ccc
::ftp::Open $ip $user $pwd
```

Comment: People still use FTP? It's much more common to use HTTP for moving files about these days (or sftp or rsync for truly large data transfers; those are both _quite_ different to FTP).

Answer (score 1):

The Open command works for me. You can try calling "set ::ftp::DEBUG 1" before you run your open command. This should give you extra error information.